# A sobering puzzle

Tags: connect-wall

Just a simple little connect wall ... I doubt the overall theme is all that hidden, but hopefully making the four groups of four will be entertaining!

Hint:

> Don't go pissing the night away thinking about the alcoholic properties ... this is about the names themselves.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BACARDI | BELLINI | CIDER | COGNAC |
| DAIQUIRI | GUINNESS | LAGER | MANHATTAN |
| PATRON | ROSE | SAKE | SMIRNOFF |
| TEQUILA | TUBA | VODKA | WHISKY |

Comment: I've been thinking for so long I don't think I can drive anymore

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the wall should be resolved as follows:

> **Group 1: Drinks that appear in the song *[Tubthumping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubthumping)* (1997) by Chumbawumba**
>  *...He drinks a **WHISKY** drink, he drinks a **VODKA** drink, he drinks a **LAGER** drink, he drinks a **CIDER** drink...*
>  (This group is suggested by the hint, in fact - 'pissing the night away' is another lyric from the song...)
>
>  **Group 2: Drinks named after a geographical location**
>  **COGNAC** - named after a [commune in France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognac,_France);
>  **MANHATTAN** - named after the [borough of New York City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan);
>  **TEQUILA** - named after a [Mexican town](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tequila,_Jalisco);
>  **DAIQUIRI** - named after a [village in Cuba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daiquir%C3%AD).
>
>  **Group 3: Drinks named after a person**
>  **SMIRNOFF** - [Pyotr Arsenievich Smirnov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyotr_Arsenievich_Smirnov);
>  **GUINNESS** - [Arthur Guinness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_Guinness);
>  **BACARDI** - [Don Facundo Bacardí Masó](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facundo_Bacardi);
>  **BELLINI** - named due to its colour resembling that of a toga in a painting by [Giovanni Bellini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giovanni_Bellini).
>
>  **Group 4: Drinks which should be spelled with an accented letter** (to differentiate them from real words in English)
>  **ROSE** (Rosé), **TUBA** (Tubâ), **SAKE** (Saké), **PATRON** (Patrón).

Comment: Fantastic job! :D